# How this regex works?

Tags: java, regex

```
System.out.println("du hast mich".replaceAll("(?<=^(.*)) ", ", $1 "));
// prints "du, du hast, du hast mich"
```

what is the mean of `^` symbol after the look behind ? (I know standard mean of this symbol is start of the line) and why dot symbol matches up to du then du hast then du hast mich.In briesf why the dot symbol didn't match the whole string?

Please give me an explanation how this regex works properly.I am wondering.Thanks for your interest.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Depending on the context, `^` can mean "beginning of the line" or "not (expression)" (but here, it is the beginning of the line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?<= )` is the syntax for [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The `^` is just the "start of string" anchor. Essentially what the regex is saying is:

"Match a space which is preceded by the start of the string and any number of characters. The characters preceding the space are the first captured group."

Comment: @MelihAltıntaş It only matches up until the end of the lookbehind, which stops just before the space (or it wouldn't be lookbehind anymore). And each space matches separately, so you get several matches.

Comment: thanks for your interest :) I didn't see the last space and i try to understand so far :))

Answer (score 2):

Kendall has the explanation. Here's the step by step.

```
du hast mich
 ^ regex hasn't matched anything so no replacement
```

writes

```
du
```

Next

```
du hast mich
  ^ regex matches
```

replaces the match with a comma and everything before the space

```
, du
```

Next

```
du hast mich
      ^ no match
```

writes

```
hast
```

Next

```
du hast mich
       ^ regex matches
```

replaces that match with a comma and everything before the space

```
, du hast
```

Next

```
du hast mich
           ^ no match
```

leaves it as is

```
mich
```

combine all that and you get

```
du, du hast, du hast mich
```

Comment: @MelihAltıntaş Note the space after the last `)` in your regex.

Comment: thanks for your interest :) I didn't see the last space and i try to understand so far :))

Answer (score 0):

That regex shouldn't work at all.  What it should do is throw an exception because of the open-ended quantifier `(.*)` in the lookbehind.  You seem to have discovered a glitch that lets you bypass that rule.  But don't use it!  It's definitely a bug, not a feature.

Java's lookbehinds have always been a little twitchy, which I attribute to its complicated *known maximum length* requirement for lookbehind subexpressions.  I've come to feel that feature was a mistake; it's just not useful to enough to justify the hassles it brought with it.  This is why I try to avoid using any quantifiers in my lookbehinds.